# If condition with OR for two values

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Is there a way to check with one value, two conditions?

Here's the example. When the admin signs up from a website, then the admin should set automatically true in the database.

```
admin_1 = admin_1@company.com
admin_2 = admin_2@company.com
if  email_from_input_field == (admin_1 || admin_2)
    user.admin == true
```

admin_1 would be set true as admin, but not admin_2.

Comment: Not much clear for me.

Comment: i edited the question. I know, i can use something like `email == admin_1 || email == admin_2`. But thats looks a bit redundant to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote it, it evaluates to

`email == true or false`

because `admin_1 || admin_2` will give a boolean value, checking whether these variables exist or not.

You could use this:

`[ admin_1, admin_2].include? email`

What it does is checks if the value of `email` is present in the array of `admin_1, admin_2`

`2.1.0 :001 > a1 = 'arindam'
 => "arindam" 
2.1.0 :002 > a2 = 'ari'
 => "ari" 
2.1.0 :003 > email = 'ari'
 => "ari" 
2.1.0 :004 > [a1,a2].include? email
 => true`

Comment: No..It is not the correct answer as per the OP's post.

Comment: `email == true or false` - if email `nil` this return `false` and if email `true` this return `false`.

Comment: This helps me and looks like this is the correct ruby way to manage a condition with multiple values but one argument. thx

Answer (score 0):

first interpret the meaning of this:

```
if  email == (admin_1 || admin_2)
    user.admin == true
```

first evaluate (admin_1 || admin_2)
 this means that, if the value of `admin_1` is `false` or `nil` then only consider `admin_2`. So if you are getting the value of `admin_1` anything other than false or nil you are actually checking a condition like this:

```
if  email == admin_1
```

just ignoring the admin_2.

if you want to check condition with both better do :

```
if ((email == admin_1) || (email == admin_2))
```